# Maintain state between redis caches on EC2 instances

Tags: caching, amazon-ec2, redis

I have a single EC2 instance. I identify users with a session key that is stored in a redis cache. When I autoscale to more EC2 instances, how will I be able to access the session keys?

For example, let's say I have EC2 instances `A` and `B`. My user, Lexy, logs signs in via the instance `A`, but then sends a request to instance `B` that requires that she's logged in. So instance `B` checks its redis cache for the session key in the header of Lexy's request and finds that it's not in instance `B`'s cache. How shoud I make sure Lexy appears logged in on all EC2 instances?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a master -> slave configuration using SYNC. Also if using EC2 make sure not to use EBS volumes...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a consistent hashing solution for redis. You're scaling redis for additional capacity, right?

If so, take a look [here](http://redis.io/topics/partitioning) and, specifically, at [twemproxy](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy). It's the current recommended method for horizontal partitioning while redis cluster is still a work in progress.

Hope it helps,